# Get the current adobe reader window title in applescript

Tags: applescript, adobe-reader

I wrote the following snippet to get the title of the firefox window,

```
tell application "Firefox"
    set window_name to name of front window
    display dialog window_name

end tell
```

it's working well, but when I change firefox to adobe, I get the following error

"Adobe Reader got an error: Can’t get name of window 1."

Any one knows how to get the window title?

Answer (score 1):

You kind of wrote the answer in the question!

```
tell application "System Events" to set adobe_windows to (get the title of every window of every process whose name contains "Adobe") as list
set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {", "}
set adobe_windows to adobe_windows as string
display dialog adobe_windows
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
```

When I get errors referring to window titles, I go to `System Events` for help. This even applies to the Finder! `System Events` can do everything the Finder can do, and sometimes more. If you have any questions, just ask. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot fireshadow52!, I'm new to Applescript so I'm going to investigate further (I'm getting an empty string but I'll do my homework before bothering you, :)) Cheers

Comment: @Pompon Make sure Adobe is actually open before you run the script. Otherwise, it *will* return an empty string. If Adobe is indeed open and it *still* returns with an empty string, just tell me and I'll update the answer for you. :)

Comment: Adobe reader is open and the script is returning an empty string, thanks so much for your help